# Probability of selecting at least 2 spades from 52 cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

Here is another combinatorics question I have encountered:

From a standard pack of 52 cards, three are selected at random. Find the probability that at least two of them are spades.

I decided to use combinations in this question but don't understand what I did wrong. A heads up would be great :)

**Solved:**
The mistake was in subtracting the spades from Case 1. - Kudos to **Boka Peer**

Case 1 becomes:
$\binom{13}{2} * \binom{39}{1}$

Case 2 (Draw 3 spades):

$\binom{13}{3}$

Adding case 1 and 2 gives:

$3328/22100$ = $64/425$

<strike>**Error:**</strike>

My Working Out:

I decided to conduct cases.

Case 1 (Draw 2 spades $*$ any other card):

$\binom{13}{2} * \binom{50}{1}$

Case 2 (Draw 3 spades):

$\binom{13}{3}$

Then I added the probabilities and divided by 22100 $(\binom{52}{3}$) which is the total amount and got $161/850$

The answer is supposedly $64/425$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comments:

Case 1 (Draw 2 spades $*$ any other card):

$\binom{13}{2} * \binom{39}{1}$.  There are 39 cards those are NOT spade.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense! Quite a silly mistake :)

Comment: It happens. Happy to help.  :)